# How to use Quartz scheduler for REST call in Dropwizard?

Tags: java, jersey, quartz-scheduler, guice, dropwizard

I want to make periodical REST request with a Dropwizard Backend. More concretely I want to make an GET request to an external REST API every minute and process the result.

I used the quartz [here](https://github.com/dropwizard-jobs/dropwizard-jobs) and now I try to use the jersey client to make a REST request. I use guice as my dependency injection.

My application class has the following methods

```
 @Override
  public void initialize(final Bootstrap<DockerwizardConfiguration> bootstrap) {
    Job everyJob = new EveryTestJob();
    bootstrap.addBundle(new JobsBundle(everyJob));
  }

  @Override
  public void run(final DockerwizardConfiguration configuration,
      final Environment environment) {
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule() {
      @Override
      protected void configure() {
        bind(HelloWorldParameter.class)
            .annotatedWith(Names.named("helloWorldParameter"))
            .toInstance(configuration.getHelloWorldParameter());
      }
    });
    JerseyClientConfiguration conf = configuration.getJerseyClientConfiguration();
    conf.setChunkedEncodingEnabled(false);
    final Client client = new JerseyClientBuilder(environment).using(conf).build(getName());

    environment.jersey().register(new ExternalServiceResource(client)); // How should that be implented with guice
    environment.jersey().register(injector.getInstance(HelloWorldResource.class));


  }
```

And my EveryTestJob class is implemented as follows

```
@Every("1s")
public class EveryTestJob extends Job {

  @Override
  public void doJob(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
    // logic run every time and time again
  }
}
```

I am unsure how I this can be organized.

Comment: Everything looks fine in code, is there any problem you are facing?

Comment: I am dont know how to inject the client object into the resource or should it be injected into the `EveryTestJob`

Comment: All the code you need for making rest call should be injected and processed in EveryTestJob

Comment: I thought that the `EveryTestJob` must be instantiated in the `initialize`  method with the `bootstrap` Jobbundle

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to figure this out for a while, and this is what I have found out:

- The JobBundle is added before any Resources so the JobExecutionContext will not include the client (https://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.2/docs/manual/internals.html)
- Tried using the injector but didn't work either (https://github.com/HubSpot/dropwizard-guice)

Finally I stumbled on [Jersey 2.0: Create repeating job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30575591/jersey-2-0-create-repeating-job) which showed how to add the client into the context!

Here's my solution:

In the resource class,

```
@Path("/myPath")
public class myResource {

    @Inject
    public myResource() {
        try {
            Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
            scheduler.getContext().put"myResource", this); // Inserts myResource into the context
        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            // Handle exception
        }
    }

    // Other stuff for api
}
```

Then in the job class (I'm using Dropwizard-jobs 2.0.1 where doJobs doesn't take in any arguments so I used execute instead),

```
@Every("10s")
public class myJob extends Job {

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        try {
            myResource res = (myResource) context.getScheduler().getContext().get("myResource");
            // Do stuff with your resource
        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            // Handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure if you have access to the ExternalServiceResource, but I hope this helps!